# pdf generation with Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4, pdf-generation, laravel-blade

I'm using `LynX39\LaraPdfMerger` to generate my pdf files from a file named `pdf.blade.php`. When it's a normal html file everything seems to be good but once generate the pdf file everything is wrong and ugly. Is there any way to make the `blade` looks like the normal `html` file? You can see the 2 images below. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

to generate the file

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.pdf_view', $data);
return $pdf->download('fiche' . '_' . time() . '.pdf');
```

`pdf file`
!https://drive.google.com/open?id=1309cGQl8sFPB22vFZTOdseBt-M7rCTjs

`html file`
!https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oSJFfRkKsraonATJa50ExH3yNN2HcQqH

Comment: you have to insert css in pdf_view page whatever css exists  in html page.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4 CDN

Comment: did you put all css links in "layouts.pdf_view" page ?

Answer (score 0):

do one thing change permission of css folder to +750.

then put css path like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css_public_path') }}" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: please! how can i change that permission
I try this ```chmod -R 750 public/css``` and added the stylesheet link but the result is the same

Comment: please do cache clear first.please change permission to 744 of public/css folder then check it.